# Input for one line is messing up, code is similar all throughout

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

Hello this program i made is supposed to obtain a height in inches (age 1-18) from the user and based off the amount, produce the an estimated height when the individual becomes an adult. The program works as inteded except when I input womens height it does not come out properly. It shows up as the numbers 1-18, compared to the mens height which shows whatever was input. This issue also messes up the equation because instead of calculating using the input number it uses 1-18. I get the error

```
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'growthChart[x]':  the readable size is '40' bytes, but '48' bytes may be read.
```

but it only shows under the line `cin >> growthChart[x][5];.` Not sure how i should go about fixing this becuase i see no issue with it and the other similar problems I looked up were in different cases.

```
int main()
{


double growthChart[19][5] = { {0,28.6,30.9},{1,42.2,44.7},{2,49.5,52.8},{3,53.8,57},{4,58,61.8},    {5,61.8,66.2},{6,65.2,70.3},
{7,69,74},{8,72,77.5},{9,75,80.7},{10,78,84.4},{11,81.1,88.4},{12,84.2,92.9},{13,87.3,96.5},    {14,91.5,98.3},
{15,96.1,99.1},{16,98.3,99.6},{17,99.3,100},{18,99.8,100} };
char choice;
bool runAgain = true;

int x;

while (runAgain)
{

    for (x = 0; x < 19; x++)

    {

        cout << "\nAge in Years " << x;

        growthChart[x][0] = x;

        cout << "\nEnter Boys height in inches:: ";

        cin >> growthChart[x][4];

        cout << "\nEnter Girls height in inches :: ";

        cin >> growthChart[x][5];

    }

    cout << "\n\n" << "The displayed height shows feet as a whole number and the decimal as     inches.";

    cout << "\n\n" << setw(10) << "Age" << setw(25) << "Boys height(inches)" << setw(25)<<     "Growth percentage" << setw(25) << "Boys height(feet/inches)"

        << setw(25) << "Girls height(inches)" << setw(25) << "Growth percentage" << setw(25) <<     "Girls height(feet/inches)";



    for (x = 0; x < 19; x++)

    {



        cout << "\n" << setw(10) << growthChart[x][0] << setw(25) << growthChart[x][4] <<     setw(25) << growthChart[x][1]<< "%" << setw(25) << ((growthChart[x][4]*(100 / growthChart[x]     [1]))/12)

            << setw(25) << growthChart[x][5] << setw(25) << growthChart[x][2] << "%" << setw(25)     << ((growthChart[x][5]*(100 / growthChart[x][2]))/12);

    }
```

Comment: `cin >> growthChart[x][5];` overflows your array when `x` is 18.  Array indexing is zero-based.  The second dimension of your array is 5, so the maximum index you can use is 4.

Comment: I understand, so if i made the max 6 instead it should work properly?

Comment: I can't say if it will work "properly", because I have no idea what these indices are supposed to represent.  But yeah, at least it won't access off the end of the array at index 5.  But why are you asking me instead of just changing the value and checking it yourself?

Comment: Yea I just checked it and it works, thank you

Comment: Strong candidate for using `std::vector` here and `push_back` so you don't overflow your fixed-length arrays.